# laravel - how to deal with model of similar type

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I am trying to model a company and its relevant employee strucutre. I have 3 tables (company, position, employee) as below, and company haveMany position, and employee haveMany position. Position belongs to company, and position belongs to employee.

However, different position have some common field like onboard date, but have some fields are different. Forexmaple, CEO has a gurantee employment period, while other position dont. Quite a number of field is different too for different position.

In that case, should I using polymorphic to model? but as the company has quite a number of different position, this will create quite a lot new table in the database.

Do you have any advice on how to model different positions?

Companies

- id
- Position

Positions

- id
- type [CEO, manager, director, clerk, etc]
- company_id
- employee_id
- Onboard Date
- Ceased Date

Employees

- id
- position id

Answer (score 1):

> In that case, should I using polymorphic to model? but as the company has quite a number of different position, this will create quite a lot new table in the database.

No, why would be?

First of all, it should be manyToMany relation and not oneToMany because if you have two companies both of those can have CEO (for example) position and if you set $position->belongsTo(Company::class); it couldn't work.

It is polymorph relation there with `positions` as polymorphic angle of that triangle.

You would need

```
// companies
id
name

// employees
id
name

// positions
id
name

// positionables
position_id
positionable_id
positionable_type
```

With this, your models would be

```
class Company extends Model
{
    public function positions()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Position::class, 'positionable');
    }
}

class Employee extends Model
{
    public function positions()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Position::class, 'positionable');
    }
}

class Position extends Model
{
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Company::class, 'positionable');
    }

    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Company::class, 'positionable');
    }
}
```

It allows you to set positions, companies and employees separately. Meaning, From dashboard you can make some new positions that will be available on frontend from select options let's say. Of course you should allow company and to employee to create new position (I suggest) and not just to use existing one but it could be out of scope of this question now: in example, when (and if) company creates new position (instead of selecting existing ones from options list), you would first create that position and store it into `positions` table and then associate company with it. Also, when using this kind of chained inputs to DB don't forget to use DB transactions. Into `positionables` table you would set other fields important for each relation (`onboard_date`, `ceased_date`, etc).
[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) is very good and consult it if something is not clear (I hope it is already).

Disclaimer: I don't know rest of your project business plan and rest of project's requirements but for these three entities this is the best structure you can go with. I have set just mandatory members to models and tables for this example. Also in offered answer, I presumed use of Laravel's naming convention that's blindly followd from docs and [this](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices) repo.

Comment: if there are 10 different positions (like director, shareholder, CEO, CFO, etc..) and each positions have 5 specific fields, do it means that positionables table would need to add 50 nullable extra columns? if there is any issues for a table with 50 nullable extra column?

Comment: No. Then you create child attribute table for `positions` table, let's name it `position_attributes` and call it with `$company->positions[0]->attributes` for example. That `position_attributes` table would have `position_id` field and `PositionAttribute` model should have `public function position() { return $this->belongsTo(Position::class); }`. Always tend to normalize tables (3NF at least) and keep only fields characteristic for exact table/entity/model. In same way in `positionables` ftable keep only fields crucial for `position <-> company|employee` relation.

Comment: For example I have CFO, Sales, Clerk position, then I would need to create 3 position_attributes table: position_cfos, position_sales, position_clerk?

Comment: `position_position_attribute` can be pivot table between `positions` and `position_attributes`. You can have manyToMany relation between those and keep `attr_key`/`attr_value` fields in `position_attributes` (field names with `attr_` prefix on purpose to avoid any collision with as it may be reserved words). 
This question is going to be bigger and bigger because we don't have defined business requirements in question and you are widening it now. Current answer is exact what question asks for. Try to make it first and let us know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields have no relationship with other tables, one possible way is to have a key-value table to store those fields and values:

```
position_fields
- id
- position_id
- key
- value
```

You can hence store the fields in `key` and the respective value in `value`. Then you may overwrite the `__get` magic method in `Position` model e.g.

```
public function __get($key){
    $position_field = $this->hasMany(PositionField::class)->where('key', $field)->first();
    return !!$position_field ? $position_field->value : $this->getAttribute($key);
}
```